# Prove there is only one orthogonal vector that satisfies $ac-bd=1$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is part of a solution manual proof for a larger problem. It glosses over that for a vector $v = \begin{pmatrix} a\\b\end{pmatrix}, \lVert v\rVert=1$  there exists exactly one vector $w = \begin{pmatrix} c\\d\end{pmatrix}\lVert w\rVert = 1$ such that $$\langle v, w \rangle = 0, \quad ad-bc=1$$
How can I prove this algebraically? I keep getting stuck with sums under roots etc....

Comment: I think a proof by contradiction should work.

Comment: hint: $ad-bc$ is the signed area of of the parallelogram formed by the vectors  $\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} c\\d\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists only two vectors $w_1,w_2$ such that $\|w_k\|=1$ and $\langle v,w_k\rangle=0$, namely
$$
\pm\begin{pmatrix}b\\-a\end{pmatrix}
$$
This can be seen by the requirement $\|w_k\|=1$ being satisfied by any vector on the unit circle (centered at the origin), and the requirement $\langle v, w_k\rangle=0$ being satisfied by the line spanned by the vectors given above. The circle and the line intersect at the two points given above.

The final requirement, $ad-bc$ is satisfied by only one of these two, for the other we have $ad-bc=-1$.